# Querying the list of event listeners registered for a given event type

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a way to identify the list of registered listeners for a given event in javascript, if so can you please list out the sample?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Comment: you can write your event handler btw, and then it's easy. see: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. You can only do this if you keep track of all event listeners yourself in your code. The simplest way would be to use a wrapper function for all your event listener assignment. I wouldn't be surprised if one of the big libraries does this for you.